# Error: ReferenceError: send is not define

Tags: javascript

```
<script>      
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("symbol").keydown(function( event ){
  $("abcd").html(event.type+":"+event.which);
});
}); 
</script>
```

every time i write a character in input type text field of name 'symbol' nothing happens and it shows error of above in the error console.How do i rectify this??

Comment: You've any other code that goes with this?

Comment: Hopefully something with `send` in it

Comment: ^ it's anybody's guess. Oh rats, the cat just dropped the @!*$ crystal ball.

Comment: I don't see how the code displayed has actually anything to deal with the title of the question.

Answer (score 2):

If the input text field has name symbol, `$("symbol")` will of course not work, because it looks for symbol tags.

Use `$("input[name='symbol']")` instead.

Comment: Agree. The error in the OP title is probably caused by some other JS on the page.